# MS SQL: Out of memory happened while accessing a critical resource

Tags: sql-server, memory

How do I go about resolving "Out of memory happened while accessing a critical resource" errors?

I have sufficient RAM (1.82TB) on a VMWare Win 2016 Std; MS SQL 2019 CU12 Ent 32 cores with max memory for the instance set to 1.7GB, allowing about 100GB for OS, R, SSIS (yes: I am less than happy with those components sharing my OLTP instance - not my call).

I have checked Resource Governor - while there are numerous different workload groups, they are all allocated to the default resource pool, with no limitation on memory set for any/each workload group.

The RAM was recently increased from 720GB to 1.82TB on the VM host, and there is only one VM server being hosted on this VMWare host.

Comment: have you seen [Function throws error: Out of memory happened while accessing a critical resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849087/function-throws-error-out-of-memory-happened-while-accessing-a-critical-resourc)? Is that the complete error message? have you captured the function/procedure throwing the error ([Extended events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) would help)?

Comment: Your Max Server Memory is set way too high. You should have around 236 GB free **just** to run Windows, plus whatever R and SSIS needs. That being said, this error is quite common with CLR, in-memory OLTP workloads, and I have seen it in columnstore as well. We definitely need more information to help you narrow it down.